# Remove the first 2 <li> content, except what you have inside the tag <label>

Tags: javascript, jquery

How do I remove the content of the first 2 `<li>`, except what you have inside the tag  `<label>` of the second `<li>`.

My structure is like this:

```
<ul>
    <li> 
        Text <label>1#</label> <input type="text" value="" />
    </li>
        <li> 
        Text <label>2#</label> <input type="text" value="" />
    </li>
        <li> 
        Text <label>3#</label> <input type="text" value="" />
    </li>
        <li> 
        Text <label>4#</label> <input type="text" value="" />
    </li>
        <li> 
        Text <label>5#</label> <input type="text" value="" />
    </li>
        <li> 
        Text <label>6#</label> <input type="text" value="" />
    </li>
        <li> 
        Text <label>7#</label> <input type="text" value="" />
    </li>
    
</ul>
```

And would have to remove the codes and stay that way:

```
<ul>  
    <li> 
        <label>2#</label> 
    </li>
        <li> 
        Text <label>3#</label> <input type="text" value="" />
    </li>
        <li> 
        Text <label>4#</label> <input type="text" value="" />
    </li>
        <li> 
        Text <label>5#</label> <input type="text" value="" />
    </li>
        <li> 
        Text <label>6#</label> <input type="text" value="" />
    </li>
        <li> 
        Text <label>7#</label> <input type="text" value="" />
    </li>
    
</ul>
```

**[DEMO CODE](http://jsfiddle.net/DDt38/)**

*(My English sucks, I hope you understood my question, and it has been clear for everyone.)*

Comment: In your example you removed the entire first `<li>` block. Is that what you want?

Comment: And you did not remove the second `<label>` tag, you said you wanted to keep only its content?

Comment: @j08691, @blex Yes, removes the first block full `<li>` without exception and the exception keeps `<label>` only for the second block of `<li>`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This removes the first list item completely, then all nodes except labels from the second list item.

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/BLGB3/)

```
$('ul li:nth-child(1)').remove();
$('ul li:nth-child(1)').contents().filter(function(){
    return !$(this).is('label');
}).remove();
```

Comment: And in case I have 2 <ul> and must do so only at first?

Comment: @user3743128 `$('ul:eq(0) li:nth-child(1)')`

Comment: @user3743128 Yes if you only want to apply to the first ul, add a filter. Otherwise it will apply to all. See this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/Aq8BL/

Comment: +1 for being the only person who understood the problem, out of all the people who answered.

Comment: What's wrong with : $('ul li:nth-child(1) input').remove(); ?

Answer (score 1):

Here's a possibility (just a quick lesson on JQuery here, but I would go for the 3rd option, see below) :

```
$('ul li:nth-child(1)').remove();
$('ul li:nth-child(1)').remove(); // child(1) ALSO, BECAUSE #2 HAS NOW BECOME #1 !

// OR MODULAR :
for (i=1; i < 3; i++)
{
    $('ul li:nth-child('+i+')').remove(); // OBVIOUSLY #3 AND #4 ARE REMOVED AS WELL.
}

// YOU CAN CAPTURE AND STORE THE LABEL CONTENT, ERASE THE CONTENT OF THE LI, AND PUT BACK THE LABEL :

for (i=1; i < 3; i++)
{
    var label_content = $('ul li:nth-child('+i+') label').html(); // GETTER
    $('ul li:nth-child('+i+')').html(''); // SETTER (set to empty)
    $('ul li:nth-child('+i+')').html('<label>'+label_content+'</label>'); // REINJECT THE LABEL
}
```

Working Fiddle here : http://jsfiddle.net/U5K5q/1/

But it looks like you just want to "hide" (display:none) your inputs... If it is the case, you may as well do :

```
for (i=1; i < 3; i++)
{
    $('ul li:nth-child('+i+') input').css('display':'none');
    $('ul li:nth-child('+i+') input').attr('disabled'); // JUST TO MAKE SURE THIS INPUT IS NOT GOING SUBMITTED
}
```

Or, 3rd option, cleaner :

```
for (i=1; i < 3; i++)
{
    $('ul li:nth-child('+i+') input').remove(); // OBVIOUSLY #3 AND #4 ARE REMOVED AS WELL.
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This could be your solution:

```
$('ul li label').each(function() {
    $(this).parent().empty().append($(this));
});
```

Fiddle:http://jsfiddle.net/FGJLg/